# T4 Template place using outside of namespace

Tags: c#, template-engine, t4

I try to use t4 template engine but it automatically includes the using directive inside the namespace block. It cannot find `System` namespace since it searches within the parent namespace where our own `MyProject.System` namespace is set.

**Folder / namespace structure**

- MyFolder
- OtherFolder
- System

**Template File**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<div>Test</div>
```

**CS File**

```
namespace MyProject.MyFolder.Templates
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
}
```

**Error**

> Namespace `Linq` could not be found in `MyProject.System`.

**Question**

How do I force t4 to put using outside of the namespace block?

Comment: Can you include the template that is creating that output?

Comment: I added it. For now i just renamed our `System` namespace which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference `System.Linq` in a non-relative way like this;

```
using global::System.Linq;
```

In case that's a useful approach.

Comment: The c# code is generated by the template itself. I just renamed our `System` namespace now.

Comment: Did you try `<#@ import namespace="global::System" #>`? Interested to know if it would have worked.